# Manipulating C# Shorthand Getter-Setter

Tags: c#, getter-setter, conditional-operator

Recently started working in C# and I am making full use of the shorthand properties (Getters-Setters) and have a question about how to constrain the setter

I have a height property as follows

```
public int height {get; set;} = 200
```

The width property however has a minimum of 10px and is thus written in the original form

```
private int width = 100
public int Width 
{
  get
  {
    return this.width;
  }
  set
  {
    this.width = value > 10 ? value : 10;
  }
}
```

My question is... Is there any way to keep the shorthand styled property yet manipulate it to have my ternary operator? Nearly all the other properties have the shorthand syntax and I like being consistent. (I know this is wrong but is something along the lines of this possible?)

```
public int width {get; set => value > 10 ? value : 10;} = 100
```

Comment: See [Expression bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties)

Comment: if your setter is going to have a lambda expression, the compiler will make you use one for the getter as well

Comment: I have never seen how this would be possible but i am interested to know for sure if there isn't a way. I have to admit that would be in some cases very convenient to have this syntax possible. It's not complicated to figure out value is the hidden auto generated private field at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the read Wyck. @Jonesopolis May I ask why? In my head they are 2 separate code blocks and when I worked with Java, they were treated in complete isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have an auto-implemented getter and a custom setter (or vice-versa).

When you write:

```
T Prop { get; set; }
```

the compiler generates a special backing field for the property with a name that is inaccessible from actual C# code (disassembling .NET Core 3.1 compilation of the above code yields a name of `<Prop>k__BackingField`) and creates a straightforward getter that returns its value and a setter that assigns `value` to it.

Now, if either your `set` or your `get` is custom, there is no universal way of auto-generating a sensible counterpart. In your case the backing field `width` is of the same type as the property itself and has the same name, only in lowercase. But one could easily have a backing field that has a different type and a different naming convention. Or the property could be a complicated combination of many different fields.

As you can see, this breaks down pretty easily, so the only feasible way an auto-generated counterpart could be implemented is "if there is a field with the same name as the property but lowercase (or lowercase preceded by an underscore, as is the standard .NET naming convention) then auto-generate the counterpart using that field". That's very specific and the complexity of implementing it does not warrant its usability, since the difference between:

```
T _prop;

T Prop
{
  get => _prop;
  set
  {
      ... // custom code
  }
}
```

and

```
T _prop;

T Prop
{
  get;
  set
  {
      ... // custom code
  }
}
```

is negligible. I'd even argue that the first one is more readable, since it specifically shows me the field being used and I don't have to look for it.

Comment: Dude! Thanks so much! This is a ridiculously well laid out explanation. I appreciate the help and it does make a lot of sense to me now. Have an awesome day!

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest you can come given C#'s language design:

```
private int width = 100;
public int Width
{
    get => width;
    set => width = value > 10 ? value : 10;
}
```

I'd recommend adding line breaks to the code to make it more readable and easy to debug; it's easier to add breakpoints to a new line than to a section of a single one.

Comment: Thanks for the added advice and a solution! much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Not as such, but you can definitely shorten the 12 line monstrosity above:

```
int width = 100;
public int Width { get => width; set => width = Math.Max(10, value); }
```